# How to make a conditional check based on different criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my Node API I need to create a conditional method which checks different criteria and on what criteria fulfill the scope result a specific value.

The scenario is that we have an array of Sites OBJ which contains keys as follow

```json
"sites":[
  {
    "id":"1",
    ...
    "countryCode":"se",
    "default":true,
    "active": true
  },
  ... more ...
],
```

This above can contain various Sites which are specific places for e.x I can have different countries, active false/true and default active true/false.

the criteria I have to check are as follow:

```
1. is default, same country, active
2. is default, same country, inactive
3. is default, any country, active
4. is default, any country, inactive
5. sites(active).length === 1
6. undefined
```

As initial part I would do as check if we have any default site at all as follow

```js
const defaultSiteKey = sites.filter(site => site.default);
const isNotDefaultSite = defaultSiteKey.length === 0;
```

That would result in

```js
const defaultSite = sites => {
  const defaultSiteKey = sites.filter(site => site.default);
  const isNotDefaultSite = defaultSiteKey.length === 0;


  const isDefaultSite = {};
  if (!isNotDefaultSite) {
    //more logic ???
    if(sites[0].countryCode === sameCountry) return siteId
    if(sites[0].countryCode !== sameCountry) return siteId
    //....
    return isDefaultSite;
  }

  return isDefaultSite;
};
```

I don't know how to make those criteria in the right way I have to result one `siteId` as `defaultSite`.

Comment: You should draw a flowchart - it will help you see all the possible variants.

Comment: I can't follow you code. For example what is `sameCountry`?

Comment: it looks like you're returning `siteId` whatever `sites[0].countryCode` is